# How do I post Telerik Calendar selected value in my page using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, kendo-ui, telerik

hey everyone i am new in telerik i tried to post telerik calendar vselected value on some page but its not working how do i post telerik calendar selected   value in my page using php.

here is my code below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <?php require_once 'wrappers/php/lib/Kendo/Autoload.php'; ?>
      <h2>Date Picker</h2>
      <?php // Instantiate a new instance of the DatePicker class and specify its 'id' $datepicker = new \Kendo\UI\DatePicker('datepicker'); // Configure the datepicker using the fluent API $datepicker->start('year') ->format('MMMM yyyy'); // Output the
      datepicker HTML and JavaScript by echo-ing the result of the render method echo $datepicker->render(); ?>
      <h2>Calendar</h2>
      <?php
        $calendar = new \Kendo\UI\Calendar('calendar');

        echo $calendar->render();
      ?>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub">
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
            $val=$_POST['datepicker'];
            echo $val;

        //    $val=$_POST['calendar'];
        //    echo $val;
        //return $val;
        }
      ?>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

my datepicker is working but calendar is not working 
any kind of example can help me.